# AngularJS jsonp is not working for me

Tags: angularjs

I am not getting the data in html page.
home.html

```
<!Doctype html>

<html ng-app="myServiceApp">

<head>    
    <title>Processing $http.jsonp() response in service</title>        
</head>

<body>

<div ng-controller="myServiceCtrl">

    <h3>Processing $http.jsonp() response in service</h3>

    <button ng-click="doJSONPRequest()">Click and make JSONP request</button>    
    <p>Data Details: {{details}}</p>    
    <p>Status Code: {{statcode}}</p>    
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

myServiceCtrl.js

```
var app = angular.module('myServiceApp', []);

app.controller('myServiceCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.doJSONPRequest = function () {

        var url = "http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/wtmpeachtest.wordpress.com/posts?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

        $http.jsonp(url)

            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                $scope.details = data.found;

                $scope.statcode = status;

            })

            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                $scope.statcode = status;

            });

    }

});
```

Comment: You don't have any `<script>` in your HTML page. So neither angular nor your script is being loaded and executed.

Comment: Other than that, your code works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/cD2PBiLAZIRxtasuJeHj?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any  in your HTML page. So neither angular nor your script is being loaded and executed.

Add the scripts, and everything will go fine.

Answer (score 1):

Until you include angular.js file its just like normal html page.
Use this below code to run this page as angular app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Processing $http.jsonp() response in service</title>        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myServiceApp', []);
        app.controller('myServiceCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

            $scope.doJSONPRequest = function () {

                var url = "http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/wtmpeachtest.wordpress.com/posts?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

                $http.jsonp(url)

                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                        console.log(data)
                        $scope.details = data.found;
                        $scope.statcode = status;

                    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                        $scope.statcode = status;

                    });

            }

        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myServiceApp" ng-controller="myServiceCtrl">
        <button ng-click="doJSONPRequest()">Click and make JSONP request</button>    
        <p>Data Details: {{details}}</p>    
        <p>Status Code: {{statcode}}</p>    
    </div>    
</body></html>
```